# zabbix api get all host names

Tags: python, zabbix

I'm using Python to query a Zabbix server in an attempt to get a list of hostids and hostnames. I'm testing with the following:

```
zapi = ZabbixAPI(server=server, log_level=debuglevel)
zapi.login(username, password)

hosts = zapi.host.get({"params":{"output":"hostid", "name"}})
print hosts
```

The above test only prints out the hostids. The host names are not retrieved.

example of output:

```
[{u'hostid': u'10084'}, {u'hostid': u'30000'}, {u'hostid': u'30001'}, {u'hostid': u'30002'}]
```

What I am doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your parameters are wrong. It must be array:

```
zapi = ZabbixAPI(server=server, log_level=debuglevel)
zapi.login(username, password)

hosts = zapi.host.get(output=["hostid", "name"])
print hosts
[{u'hostid': u'10084', u'name': u'Zabbix server'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, Jan! For anyone else reading, I switched from zabbix_api to pyzabbix to get the above to work.

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
from zabbix_api import ZabbixAPI


server = ""   #address   
username = ""              #user   
password = ""     # pass  


zapi = ZabbixAPI(server = server)
zapi.login(username, password)

hostgroups = zapi.hostgroup.get({"output": "extend", "sortfield": "name"}) # for groupid
hosts = zapi.host.get({"groupids": "36", "output": ["hostid","name", "host"]}) # for host and name
```

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for the [Express42/zabbixapi](https://github.com/express42/zabbixapi) version of this in Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'pp'
require 'zabbixapi'

hostname = 'hostname.domain.com'

zbx = ZabbixApi.connect(
  url: 'http://localhost/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php',
  user: 'Admin',
  password: 'zabbix'
)
pp zbx.query(
  method: 'host.get',
  params: {
    output: %w[extend hostid name],
    filter: {
      name: hostname
    }
  }
)
```

Remove the `filter` object to return ALL hosts in the Zabbix database.